# How to treat NULLs like '' (empty data) in comparison WHERE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that if you try to compare a NULL value to something else. It being NULL makes the whole statement NULL.

```
table.ColumnA = NULL
table.ColumnB = 'something'
```

If I do something like

```
where table.ColumnA <> table.ColumnB
```

It will not work.

I know you can do something like,

```
(NOT (a <> b OR a IS NULL OR b IS NULL) OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL))
```

But my query is already pretty long and complicated. Trying to add this routine for every column would be a nightmare.

I was hoping there was an easier way to just temporarily treat NULL as ''

Comment: No, `NULL` and `''` are completely different values. Though you *can* get `NULL` to behave like other values with the equality operators, the method is ***not*** recommend as it does not follow ISO standards, and the property isn't allowed to be switched off for some functionality in SQL Server. Using `IS NULL` (and `IS NOT NULL`) is always the way to go.

Comment: I suppose you could use `ISNULL(column, '')`

Comment: In there `WHERE`, however, I really don't recommend that @DavidG . Such a clause is not SARGable. As the OP is explicitly talking about a `WHERE` here, then they really shouldn't be using `ISNULL` on the columns.

Comment: @Larnu I know, but since we know nothing about the rest of the structure or query, what else can we do.

Comment: Use `IS NULL`, @DavidG . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for `a <> b` with `NULL` values is:

```
where (a <> b or a is null and b is not null or a is not null and b is null)
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support the standard `is distinct from` clause, which would make this much simpler.

If there are values that you know will never be used, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
where coalesce(a, '<null>') <> coalesce(b, '<null>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful blanket removing nulls, but if you need a quick solution to treat NULL as an empty string while preserving non-nulls you can use the coalesce function:

```
COALESCE(columnname, '')
```

Docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15